# After installing SQL Server 2019 CU2, SQL Server Agent stops working

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

I have installed SQL Server 2019 CU2 and after that SQL Server Agent start is consuming too much CPU resulting into skip job schedules.

Although the agent service is running but it looks like hang and didn't process / kick off any jobs.

Once I re-start the Agent service it starts working again (cpu = 0), but then after some time 1-2 hours CPU intake in high and jobs do not run.

Is anybody else facing same issue with SQL Server 2019 CU2?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: adjust your memory limit and observe

Comment: This really doesn't have anything to do with **programming** (which *this site* is **all about**), but with DB administration - so it's off-topic here and belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) - voting to move.

Answer (score 0):

There is already a thread for this on [DBA StackExchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/260190/sql-server-agent-fails-after-installing-sql-server-2019-cu2). The issue was introduced in CU2 and will be fixed in CU3. If you're facing this, the workaround is to revert to CU1 until you are able to upgrade to CU3.